# Deserialize LocalDateTime from String with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to deserialize a `String` to `LocalDateTime` with Jackson but it doesn't work.

I have a data class with a LocalDateTime field:

```
@Data
public class Registration {
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;
}
```

I added the special Jackson datatype modules:

```
compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310")
```

The serialization works fine with:

```
new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule()).writeValueAsString(registration);
```

Result String:

```
{"timestamp":"2018-09-03 10:09:35"}
```

But the deserialization doesn't work with:

```
new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule()).readValue(json.traverse(), Registration.class)
```

As error I get:

```
Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDateTime` from String "2018-09-03 10:09:35": 
    Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDateTime: 
        (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2018-09-03 10:09:35' could not be parsed: 
            Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: 
                {MinuteOfHour=9, NanoOfSecond=0, SecondOfMinute=35, MicroOfSecond=0, MilliOfSecond=0, HourOfAmPm=10},
                ISO resolved to 2018-09-03 of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

What am I missing? I'm confused that the serialization works but the deserialization doesn't.

---

**MWE:** (small gradle Java project)

Main.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.TreeNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Registration registration = new Registration();
        registration.setTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now());

         ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

         String s = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(registration);
         TreeNode treeNode = objectMapper.readTree(s);

         //Fails here:
         Registration registration1 = objectMapper.readValue(treeNode.traverse(), Registration.class);

        System.out.println(registration1);
    }
}

class Registration {
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;

    public Registration() {
    }

    public LocalDateTime getTimestamp() {
        return this.timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
        this.timestamp = localDateTime;
    }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'dateMWE'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 10

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.6")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.9.6")
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is not related with JSON deserialization, but rather with the time format string:

```
pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
```

Please notice that the hours are set as `hh`: this is a 12-hour formatter, which requires "AM" or "PM" values.

If the pattern is changed to

```
pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
```

the problem should be solved.

Comment: That is true. I played around with the pattern but I couldn't find any detailed documentation on what patterns/keywords exist. Could you add a link to a documentation or listing of all possible format options?

Comment: @Spen: DataTimeFormatter patterns are documented in the standard [Java API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: Thansk for saving my day. I refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/54819859/4093741 this answer, but code not work. The error log is not very intuitive.

Answer (score 14):

Your ObjectMapper is not managed by spring since you are creating object with new. Configure `ObjectMapper` as Bean in your configuration file. You need to register the `DateTimeFormat` with your `LocalDateTimeDeserializer`. Then set  your Deserializer in JavaTimeModule.

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule();
    LocalDateTimeDeserializer localDateTimeDeserializer = new
            LocalDateTimeDeserializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    module.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, localDateTimeDeserializer);
    ObjectMapper objectMapperObj = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json()
            .modules(module)
            .featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
            .build();
    return objectMapperObj;
}
```

Set the above configuration in your Spring configuration.