# ModelMapper returns null for LocalDateTime after conversion

Tags: java, mapper

Entity class

```
class User {
  String name;
  LocalDateTime date;
}
```

And dto

```
class UserDto {
  String name;
  String date;
}
```

When I transform the dto into an entity object

```
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
public User dtoToEntityConverter(UserDto dto) {
   return modelMapper.map(dto, User.class);
}
```

I get the date field of the dto object in this format:

```
"2021-03-17T23:05:33.371479"
```

and after the conversion I get NULL Why doesn't ModelMapper convert LocalDateTime?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jackson converting LocalDatetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53820977/jackson-converting-localdatetime)